# How to implement Resolve interface in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-guards

I know that to implement resolve guard, we do something like this

```
class PostsResolveGuard implements Resolve<somethingInsideHere>{
  resolve(): boolean {
    if(data is present)
      return true;
    else 
      return false;
  }
}
```

And below is my route which is using above guard

```
  { 
    path: ':id',
    component: SomeComponent,
    resolve: {
      isDataPresent: PostsResolveGuard
    }
}
```

so what is actually we have to replace in place of `somethingInsideHere`.
Does it depend if I change it according to `Resolve<true>` or `Resolve<false>`. How the routes are resolved in this situation.
Did the routes always resolve irrespective of what we specify in this situation.

Comment: You're confusing resolves and guards. They're not the same thing. A guard is used to prevent the router to go to a route in some situations. A resolve is used to provide data to the activated component, instead of loading this data from the component itself.

Answer (score 1):

It's the type of data it resolves to:

```
class PostsResolveGuard implements Resolve<boolean>{
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Resolve<any>
```

if you want to return data instead boolean value you can use this as safeside in typescript

Comment: I would suggest to always use strict typings instead of that implicit `any`.

Comment: 'if you want to return data(object/array)'  I mentioned above cause @Chandra Shekhar is using 'if(data is present)' in his code

Comment: But then you could still implement an interface or class (model) which represents that data, right?